# How does one specify a generic class type with an unknown generic type to be suplied in a method type argument

Tags: java, generics

The below gives me a **"type KeyType does not have Type paramters"**.  Note that AttributeKey does have a type parameter and I want the input to getAttribute method to use a specific class that extends AttributeKey with the AttType.  I havn't yet found if this is possible or how to do it if it is. :)

```
public interface AttributeMap<KeyType extends AttributeKey> 
{
    public <AttType> AttType getAttribute(KeyType<AttType> key);
}
```

Comment: Can you supply the definitions of your various types?

Comment: In one place you indicate that KeyType does not have parameters ("KeyType extends AttributeKey"), and in another you indicate that it does KeyType<AttType> key Make up your mind.

Comment: You can't really do this.  You can't have two generic types `T1` and `T2` and then use `T1<T2>`.

Comment: Annoying - I also wish there was a void type :)